# Why is the shortcut missing for EDIT/FILL/JUSTIFY from excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, shortcuts

I use Microsoft Excel 2010 and I am no longer able to find the shortcut icon that allowed me to use "EDIT/FILL/JUSTIFY" by just clicking on the icon.

Please note that there ase two "justify" within excel - One "concatenates" the text from a number of cells into one cell and the other evens out the text within the cell. I am after the icon for the the Justify that concatenates

Does anyone know how to do this in excel 2010?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Your question is confusing because you are talking about two things. Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question to clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for the Fill → Justify command? It's in the `Home` tab in the `Editing` section. The middle icon on the left (the one with the down arrow) is for Fill. The last item in the menu is Justify.

[image: editing]

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood your question, I think that you mean "Merge & Centre"? This is on the right hand side of the "Alignment" section of the Home bar.

It merges the selected cells and centres the result.

Comment: Thanks but No - my "justify" brings the content/text of the cells I choose to highlight into one cell - "merge" combines a number of cells into one and only retains the text for one cell

Answer (score 0):

"[Alt]+EIJ" -- Use the old short cut keys: Highlight your text area and go [Alt]+E, then I, then J.  There also is a "FILL" icon in the home/edit ribbon: "up, down, left right, across worksheets, series and justify".

Answer (score 0):

The ALT-E; I; J function works just fine for people like us who are used to the old menus.

The problem is how to find the equivalent set of commands in the newer versions of Excel with Newer Menus. Is it possible that they forgot to port this command to the new UI, but left the funcionality behind?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Instead of posting a second answer, please edit your first one. Also, please do not ask questions in the answer box.

Answer (score 0):

A little searching in the menus took me to:  Home--> Fill--> [Dropdown] --> Justify.

This is how they like to do it now.

FWIW, I've found free executables which will give you and the users you support the Old Windows/Office `97 Menus.